# How does parsing the `multipart/form-data` http request work?

Tags: java, forms, file, http, networking

#### Intro

Currently I'm working on simple file server written in Java that uses sockets for communication. During this project I got interested in format of http requests and would like to replicate this in my project. I'd like to do it on low-level apis, using only sockets to get a taste of how this all works under the hood.

#### tldr;

Question is pretty straightforward, it is located in last section of post. Everything else is explaination and my understanding of the problem.

#### Prerequisites

In below examples I'll be using **simplified** code with sockets to show how I understand things. I'm also assuming presence of below variables:

```
Socket socket = server.accept();
DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
```

#### Parsing Http Request

Okay, so parsing exemplary `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` http request (or similar) seems pretty understandable to me, but if I'm wrong please correct me.
Having example request:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 64
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

name=John%20User&request=Send%20me%20one%20of%20your%20catalogue
```

Sample server can parse this request in that way:

```
// read start-line of request
String startLine = input.readline();
...

// read all headers till you encounter empty line
String header;
while (!(header = input.readLine()).equals("")) {
  ...
}

// read body
int len = <Content-Length header value>;
byte[] body = new byte[len];
input.read(body, 0, len);
...
```

#### Parsing `multipart/form-data` http request

And here is my main question. Let's have an exemplary multipart request.

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=boundary
Content-Length: 465

--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

John
--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="avatar"; filename="avatar.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

<some binary data>
--boundary--
```

I'm not sure how parsing of such a request should look like. Start-line and headers can be parsed in similar way as in earlier example, but how to deal with body, especially when there is binary data in it. I had some ideas but consider them to be wrong/not sufficient.

#### My Attempt

My try was to read body as a string. Later this body could be divided into parts using value of boundary and then server could work on that separated parts (e.g. extract headers, do something with value and so on). It could look like that:

```
int len = <Content-Length header value>;
byte[] byteBody = new byte[len];
input.read(byteBody, 0, len);

String boundary = <extracted from header>;
String body = new String(byteBody);
String bodyParts = body.split(boundary)
...
```

And then I faced a problem, it wont' work for binaries. Conversion of `byte[]` to `String` and then again to `byte[]` (to write file on server) cannot work for files. That's because default encoding is ASCII and it doesn't support negative values. I did a small test, here are results.

```
byte[] arr1 = new byte[] { -1, -2, -3 };
String str1 = new String(arr1);
byte[] arr2 = str1.getBytes();

// arr1 = [-1, -2, -3]
// arr2 = [-17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67]
```

After gaining that knowledge I searched for a solution to this problem. I think that `base64` encoding could resolve my problem but it looks like a workaround to me and has its drawbacks:

- making file size larger,
- need for server and client to implement encoding/decoding for `base64`.

I also found many examples and did a simple node.js server to prove this that in case of `multipart/form-data` request body files  definitely can be sent in binary format, not in `base64` one.

#### Confusion

I'm a little bit confused now. I don't know how could I parse `multipart/form-data` request body so that I'm not converting it to string but still could break it into separate parts using value of `boundary`. I thought about reading this body byte by byte and somehow detect boundaries, but this doesn't seem to me as a good nor effective approach.

I'm really curious what's the correct way to accomplish that task and what is the standard for parsing that type of request bodies.

Answer (score 1):

The body format is like this:

1. `--` followed by the boundary
2. Any number of headers, similar to the headers of the root HTTP request
3. An empty line, similar to that between the headers of the root HTTP request and the root body
4. The part body
5. Repeat 1-4 for other parts
6. `--` followed by the boundary followed by `--`

Instead of using split, I'd parse the body line by line; if you encounter a boundary you finish the previous part (nothing to be done for the first one). If you encounter the body end you're done.

Comment: Hmm I think that's a way to go, but I have some questions:
----------
[1] To check whether we encountered `--` + boundary we have to transform every line to `String` and then make compairson. It can be a performance issue with larger files, isn't it?
----------
[2] Is reading line-by-line performant? Wouldn't it be better to somehow make use of `DataInputStream.read(byte[] b, int off, int len)` to read many bytes at once?
----------
[3] Shouldn't we make use of `Content-Length` header somehow? Or maybe this header has a different purpose?

Comment: You have a valid point about converting to string. The thing is, part of the body _is_ text (meta data, like the boundaries and headers); only the bodies aren't. You could try searching for `\r\n\r\n` in bytes; everything before it is text, everything after is the body. The content length header doesn't have to be present, so I wouldn't trust it too much.